# How to route to the default controller instead of index.html?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Instead of routing to index.html, I want my control to go to the login controller in rails when i go to http://localhost:3000 . How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to set root path in `config/routes.rb`, example:

`root 'login#index'`

Comment: In the latest rails you don't have to delete /public/index.html as it doesn't exist..

Answer (score 0):

On latest version go on 
**config/routes.rb**
and replace with home#index with your default controller 
Rails.application.routes.draw do

root :to => 'home#index'
end

Answer (score -1):

In addition to NARKOZ's answer, you might want to check out the [RailsGuides Getting Started guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html).